# three.js mousepick(raycaster) not working on loaded models

Tags: three.js

I have a problem with mousepick, when mouse is over a mesh, it shows picked, but it does not pick it when mouse is over a loaded model (3ds).

My code:

```
// raycasting
export function cameraPick() {
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
    for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
        var intersection = intersects[ i ];
        var obj = intersection.object;
        return obj;
    }
    return null;
}

// rendering
main loop
 var animate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    media.renderer.render(scene, camera);
    var v = media.cameraPick();
    if (v) {
        v.position.x+=.1;
    }
 };
```

Comment: Try this: `var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );`. Set the second parameter to `true`.

Comment: You're welcome :) Feel free to read the docs :) https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObjects

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `camera.updateProjectionMatrix()` after you changed states of the scene (like animation, new model in scene or whatever new in the scene...).

More: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.updateProjectionMatrix

Answer (score 0):

solution from  prisoner849

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
```